# using ftp or webdav?

Tags: ftp, webdav

if i want to mount remote folders in my mac and use them as a local one, should i use webdav over ftp?

basically, i have read that webdav is better than ftp (old protocol).

does this mean that i should never use ftp and only webdav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to use `nfs` or `samba` or `afp` - a protocol intended for network file shares and remote mounts, rather than `ftp` which is meant for *file transfer*.

You might also consider `sshfs`.

---

Update: I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebNFS today, and that may also be of use in your search.

Comment: how are the above mentioned protocols compared to webdav?

Comment: well, based on the wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), WebDAV is a tool that sits on top of http for file editing. So it doesn't run over ftp at all, from what I've read.

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV is more favourable, because it is based on http/https. Most private and corporate networks will work without having to change any firewall settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac Finder can mount a WebDAV share as a file system and makes a remote WebDAV server appear as a local disk. WebDAV is also designed to be secure over the internet and can use secure (HTTPS) connections.

I recommend installing an easy to use WebDAV server that provides a web based gui for managing users and privileges. Take a look at BarracudaDrive:
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/

The Mac Finder WebDAV tutorial:
http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/tutorials/WebDAV-Mac-Finder.lsp